# Why does std::bit_width return 0 for the value 0, shouldn't it return 1?

Tags: c++, c++20

`std::bit_width` finds minimum bits required to represent an integral number `x` as `1+floor(log(x))`

Why does `std::bit_width` return 0 for the value 0? Shouldn't it return 1, Since the number of bits required to represent 0 is 1?

Also, I think the `1` in the formula is an offset.

Comment: The standard specifies this behavior explicitly, but doesn't give any motivation for it.

Comment: Why should it return 1? If you want to hold zero apples, you need zero baskets, no? So for example if you were to store data as a length and a pointer to a buffer of variable length, you wouldn't even have to use any buffer at all to represent zero because you would have a length of zero to begin with.

Comment: It could be to match the behavior of instructions available on common CPUs.  For instance with this behavior it can be implemented with x86 `lzcnt` and a subtract, with no branches.

Comment: I think, we need atleast one digit to represent the number 0. If we were to describe absence of number then I think it would require 0 length.

Comment: One interpretation is it gives the number of bits you need to store an arbitrary value between 0 and x inclusive.  When x is 0, then your value will always be 0 and you don't need to store it at all, so you need no bits.

Comment: It's also logical from another perspective: it returns the position of the highest-value 1-bit from the right, starting with 1, so 0 would indicate there being no 1-bit at all. Or, from another perspective: 2^0=1, so a 0-bits-long number can represent exactly 1 state: zero. Therefore, zero bits are enough to represent the number zero.

Comment: @rohitt: yes you need the length zero, but this is no different from having to either store the length or know the maximum possible length in advance either way. If you want to represent the number 5, you need 3 bits, but you additionally need to remember somehow that you need 3 bits, otherwise you couldn't differentiate the number 5 from a larger number including more bits when they come in a bitstream. And with zero it's no different, you need 0 bits to store it but you need to still store or somehow remember how much you need to read/write - nothing in this case.

Comment: We don't really need one digit to represent zero. Using one digit for zero is needed only inside a human-readable sentence where we need to detect the presence of a number. Otherwise, when we already know there is a number there, the empty sequence of digits is a perfectly good representation for zero, which is also more regular. Try writing an algorithm to convert naturals into variable-length bit strings and vice versa: it's *easier* if we represent zero as the empty string. Indeed, when we need the one-digit zero, we need to implement a special case just for that.

Comment: @CherryDT There are two variants of `bit_width(x)`: "number of bits required to encode `x`" and "size of the smallest concrete object that can store `x`". The former is better for variable-length codes, while the latter helps to avoid inconvenient edge cases in bit-packed data structures.

Comment: Echoing others - another way to consider this. If you only want to record 'only zero', there is nothing to actually record because zero does not need to be distinguished against any other value. You only need to record a value, using 1 or more bits, when there is an actual *choice* of values.

Answer (score 78):

There is a strange bit of history to `bit_width`.

The function that would eventually become known as `bit_width` started life as `log2`, as part of a proposal [adding integer power-of-two functions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0556r0.html). `log2` was specified to produce UB when passed 0.

Because that's how logarithms work.

But then, things changed. The function later became `log2p1`, and [for reasons that are not specified was given a wider contract](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0556r1.html) ("wide contract" in C++ parlance means that more stuff is considered valid input). Specifically, 0 is valid input, and yields the value of 0.

Which is *not* how logarithms work, but whatever.

As C++20 neared standardization, a [name conflict was discovered (PDF)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/n4844.pdf#page=94). The name `log2p1` happens to correspond to the name of an IEEE-754 algorithm, but it's a radically different one. Also, functions in other languages with similar inputs and results use a name like `bit_length`. So it [was renamed to `bit_width`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1956r0.pdf).

And since it's not pretending to do a logarithm anymore, the behavior at 0 can be whatever we want.

Indeed, [the Python function `int.bit_length` has the exact same behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types). Leading zeros are not considered part of the bit length, and since a value of `0` contains all leading zeros...

Comment: Very minor quibble, but I don't think it's accurate to say "UB when passed 0... Because that's how logarithms work". UB means "can do literally anything including having effects way outside the return value of this function". In particular, the behavior of the newer spec is 100% compliant with the older one, because "return 0" is a perfectly valid implementation of UB.

Comment: @psmears: "*including having effects way outside the return value of this function*" That's what happens when you take the logarithm of 0 as well. It is a thing you cannot do, and if you do it, then your math is broken and ceases to be actual math.

Comment: It's perfectly valid (and useful) in mathematics to [extend the real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) to include plus/minus infinity, and to define log 0 to be minus infinity. Or to treat log as a [partial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function) on the reals. This answer currently says "that is _not_ how logarithms work" about a behavior that is 100% conformant with the part you describe as "that _is_ how logarithms work", which seems a bit inconsistent :)

Comment: @psmears so what's tan 90

Comment: The function formerly known as `log2p1` actually does work exactly like a logarithm; the issue is that the formula it evaluates is not `floor(log(n) + 1)` but `ceil(log(n + 1))`. Why the committee did not describe it using the second formula, which works for all `n`, but instead used the first one which has an awkward discontinuity at `n=0` and therefore needs to be described more wordily, is anyone's guess (this is the *C++* standard committee we're talking about, after all).

Comment: @notmyrealname, `tan(90)` is approximately -1.9952.  `tan(90°)` on the other hand...

Answer (score 15):

Because mathematically it makes sense:

```
bit_width(x) = log2(round_up_to_nearest_integer_power_of_2(x + 1))
bit_width(0) = log2(round_up_to_nearest_integer_power_of_2(0 + 1))
             = log2(1)
             = 0
```

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate what was said in the comments:

Assume "bit width" means "least number of bits required to store the (nonnegative integer) number". Intuitively we need at least `log2(n)` bits rounding up, so it is a formula close to `ceil(log2(n))`, so 255 would require `ceil(log2(255)) = ceil(7.99..) = 8` bits, but this doesn't work for powers of 2, so we can add a fudge factor of 1 to `n` to get `ceil(log2(n+1))`. This happens to be mathematically equivalent to `1+floor(log2(n))` for positive n, but `log2(0)` is not defined or defined as something unuseful like negative infinitiy in the floor version.

If we use the ceiling formula for 0, we get the result. You can also see I didn't write out leading zeros, and as Nicol Bolas points out, 0 is all leading zeros.

| n | bin(n) | bit_width(n) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 1000 | 4 |
| 7 | 111 | 3 |
| 6 | 110 | 3 |
| 5 | 101 | 3 |
| 4 | 100 | 3 |
| 3 | 11 | 2 |
| 2 | 10 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 |  | 0 |